# Cloudflare plugin preg_replace improvement

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am a complete newbie in PHP, so sorry in advance if my question looks naive.

There is a plugin (actuallly very popular Cloudflare SSL for Wordpress), which is meant for converting http links to https, and it looks like that:

before:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="A B &raquo; Feed" href="http://site.biz/feed/" />
```

after:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="A B &raquo; Feed" href="//site.biz/feed/" />
```

Here is it a code which does this:

```
 if (is_null($content_type) || substr($content_type, 0, 9) === 'text/html') {
    // replace href or src attributes within script, link, base, and img tags with just "//" for protocol
    $re     = "/(<(script|link|base|img|form)([^>]*)(href|src|action)=[\"'])https?:\\/\\//i";
    $subst  = "$1//";
    $return = preg_replace($re, $subst, $buffer);
```

And everything is good except the fact that this plugin is not able to process the links like that:

```
<div  class="dslc-modules-section " style="background-color:rgb(14, 134, 219);background-image:url();background-image:url(http://site.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CloudPatches.jpg);background-position:center center;background-size:cover;padding-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px;">
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to improve this part of code to make it more perfect?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the http :

```
background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CloudPatches.jpg)
```

Comment: The code provided above is what we see via View Code in browser) So we cannot just edit it. Content is generated dynamically.